# How do I install my Lexmark X1270 printer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing

I have been trying for days to install the above-mentioned printer under 12.04.  Under Hardy (8.04) it went fine.  Is it possible under 12.04 LTS at all?

Comment: Please note that this is an English site only, please re-write your question in English.

Comment: It's been Google-translated. Maybe it'll be useful to someone

Comment: You did not tell us what your problems with the installation of the printer are. You attach it to the usb, open the printers dialog, then what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the software drivers and installing them into linux, just google the brand, model, and make and then type drivers into google, and find their offical website, and under downloads, there should be our hardware driver. hope this helps.